# C#: Download file: BADRESPONSE: Unexpected token %

Tags: c#, download

I am trying to download a pdf file from server using:

```
string file = "C:\\Users\\....\\Files\\Export\\101\\1011\\1011080.pdf"

System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                   "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(file) + ";");

response.TransmitFile(file);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

But I receive this error:

> Status Code: 200 Status Text: BADRESPONSE: Unexpected token %

[image: badresponseimage]

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Maybe it's because the Content-Type is set to text/plain? Shouldn't you set a  MIME type for PDF?

Comment: `response.ContentType = "application/pdf";` what they said ^

Comment: tried that but still the same error

Comment: @Matt didn't work either

Comment: Judging by [this](https://github.com/Novik/ruTorrent/issues/1490), it may be a problem on the server. Do you have access to the relevant part of the server log? Are you able to download other files normally (PDF and non-PDF)?

Comment: @S.L.Barth In another application I am using the same way and I can download non-pdf files. Maybe there is a setting in web.config?

Comment: Could be. Also, does the server have access to that file? (I _think_ if it doesn't, it shouldn't give a 200. But I'm surprised it's giving a 200 at all... so let's see if we can rule that out.)  Also, the server logs might just tell us something.

Comment: @S.L.Barth im working on localhost

Comment: @aggicd: Is this an ajax or partial callback? Can you share how you are using this function? Because file download needs complete postback to server

Comment: @Sivaprasath its from the directevent of a button

Answer (score 0):

You set the wrong value for the Content-Type header. It is set to `text/plain`. As @Matt points out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51875581/c-download-file-badresponse-unexpected-token#comment90702538_51875581), it should be set to `application/pdf`.